# getting error in asterisk "ast_udptl_new_with_bindaddr: No UDPTL ports remaining'

Tags: linux, voip, asterisk

I am using Asterisk 1.4.18.1 I am getting the error "ast_udptl_new_with_bindaddr: No UDPTL ports remaining" when ever the calls on server reaches to 100 and after this error my calls getting disconnected. My operating server is Red Hat 3.4.6-3. Kindly suggest me something to resolve the issue.

Comment: Please post what's in your `udptl.conf`, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it may be difficult to find assistance as Asterisk [1.4 was made end-of-life last April](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+Versions).

UDPTL is the common transport for T.38. Which, adds to the fun. I recommend you disable T.38 fax if you're not using it.

However, it may also be that your specification of start and end port in `/etc/asterisk/udptl.conf` is too low. Here's what's in the default/example `udptl.conf` as of Asterisk 1.8:

```
[general]
udptlstart=4000
udptlend=4999
udptlfecentries = 3
udptlfecspan = 3
use_even_ports = no
```

Comment: I am also getting this error rtp.c:891 ast_rtcp_read: RTCP Read too short

Comment: no, still not and issue happening only when call reaches more 100. Also I can not disable T.38 because I am using it in my server.